# Sharing custom macros and custom Word Ribbon with others

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ms-word

My colleagues and I use Word 2010 and Sharepoint.

I have written some custom macros with VBA and I have also customized the ribbon to add a tab to access these macros.

What is the best way of sharing these macros and the ribbon with my colleagues? (involving manual effort on the part of my colleagues as little as possible.)

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is rather too broad for Stack Overflow. A lot depends on how you have customized the ribbon and what the code is intended for. If you have simply used the Customize Ribbon option you won't be able to share your customizations. Both the ribbon xml and code need to be in the same template. If the ribbon/code is for general use then it needs to be located in the Startup folder for Word. If it is for a specific template then you just need to make that template available.

Comment: This would be better posted in Word Answers http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or Super User https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word. It is not really a programming question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic As Mr. Rylatt observed, the customization must be done at the XML level, not using Customize the Ribbon. See http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html The ribbon customization and macros should be stored in the same template.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way for excel, hope its helpful.

First, you could write all your macros in Personal excel file. Which is located in the location mentioned below. You could go-ogle how to create Personal excel file if you dont, there are easy ways to do it.
C:\Users****\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART

Second, share the Personal excel file directly to your colleagues and ask them enable Personal macro (by recording a macro and saving it in Personal Macro - details can be found in an easy google search)

Third, Save all your UI customization.
Open this customization file in Notepad++ or Notepad or excel.
Search for your Username(****) and replace with your colleagues Username.
Share this UI customization file to your colleague and import in excel in Ribbon customization settings.

This worked for me, hope it helps !